# How to detect if collection contain instance of specific type?

Tags: c#, collections

Suppose I create collection like

```
Collection<IMyType> coll;
```

Then I have many implelentations of `IMyTypem` like, T1, T2, T3...

Then I want know if the collection coll contains a instance of type T1. So I want to write a method like

```
public bool ContainType( <T>){...}
```

here the param should be class type, not class instance. 
How to write code for this kind of issue?

Comment: Can you use LINQ to Objects?
Which version of C# are you using?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do:

```
 public bool ContainsType(this IEnumerable collection, Type type)
 {
      return collection.Any(i => i.GetType() == type);
 }
```

And then call it like:

```
 bool hasType = coll.ContainsType(typeof(T1));
```

If you want to see if a collection contains a type that is convertible to the specified type, you can do:

```
bool hasType = coll.OfType<T1>().Any();
```

This is different, though, as it will return true if coll contains any subclasses of T1 as well.

Comment: Then, How to call this method? Coll.COntainsType(T1)? it is not accepted in VS. I got error said: 'T1' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'